# VBA Function slower than Excel Formula

Tags: vba, excel

I've replaced the following horrendous Excel formula (values and names have been replaced):

```
=IF(AND(SourceTable[@Field1]="Value1",SourceTable[@Field2]="Value2"),"Result1",
    IF(SourceTable[@Field2]="Value3","Result2",
        IF(AND(SourceTable[@Field1]="Value4",SourceTable[@Field3]="Value5"),"Result3",
            IF(AND(SourceTable[@Field1]="Value6",OR(SourceTable[@Field3]="Value7",SourceTable[@Field3]="Value8")),"Value9",
                VLOOKUP(SourceTable[@Field1];MatchingTable;2;0)))))
```

With a VBA Function so it would be easier to read and supposedly faster:

```
Function CUSTOMFUNCTION(oRngField1 As Range, oRngField2 As Range, oRngField3 As Range) As String

    'If imbrication
    If (oRngField1 = "Value1" And oRngField2 = "Value2") Then
        CUSTOMFUNCTION = "Result1"
        Exit Function
    ElseIf oRngField2 = "Value3" Then
        CUSTOMFUNCTION = "Result2"
        Exit Function
    ElseIf oRngField1 = "Value4" Then
        If oRngField3 = "Value5" Then
            CUSTOMFUNCTION = "Result3"
            Exit Function
        ElseIf (oRngField3 = "Value6" Or oRngField3 = "Value7") Then
            CUSTOMFUNCTION = "Result4"
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If

    'Vlookup if no match before
    Dim sTableMatchingFieldLookup As String
    Dim sTableMatchingFieldResult As String
    sTableMatchingFieldLookup = "MatchingTable[Field1]"
    sTableMatchingFieldResult = "MatchingTable[Field2]"
    CUSTOMFUNCTION = Range(sTableMatchingFieldResult)(Application.Match(oRngField1, Range(sTableMatchingFieldLookup), 0))

End Function
```

I get the same result as the function however it does it two times longer than the formula when working with 2k rows. Why isn't the code faster than the Excel formula? Can it be improved? The file is expected to grow so it means the code will be of no use.

Edit: Using more arguments improved the macro, see my response below.

Comment: Why replace the names? It takes away meaning, which makes the code pretty hard to read and ultimately to review.

Comment: inbuild excel function are almost always faster than UDFs because Communication between Vba and Excel incurs a significant overhead.

Comment: Calling VBA from Excel is pretty fast...as long as you don't use any of Excel's features. Don't use any worksheet functions (use the VBA equivalents); don't use any Range objects. If you really need a speedup, build an XLL.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I know sorry about that, my company is a little paranoid about everything but I can ensure you it has meaning on the code. I will take time to use fake names instead for better comprehension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for answering late. I had to change the function due to other macros that glitched and got great improvement in terms of speed through the following code:

```
Function GetFruitType(colProductTypeRange As Range, colProductNameRange As Range, currentProductNameRange As Range, _
                      currentCodeRange As Range, currentProductDetailRange As Range) As String

    'Tests for the exceptions
    If (currentProductNameRange = "BEETROT" And currentProductDetailRange = "SUGAR") Then
        GetFruitType = "SUGAR"
        Exit Function
    ElseIf currentProductDetailRange = "TREE" Then
        GetFruitType = "PLANT"
        Exit Function
    ElseIf currentProductNameRange = "TOMATO" Then
        If currentCodeRange = "ADORATION" Then
            GetFruitType = "FRUIT"
            Exit Function
        ElseIf (currentCodeRange = "ALICANTE" Or currentCodeRange = "BEEFSTEAK") Then
            GetFruitType = "VEGETABLE"
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If

    'Mathing table if no exception found
    GetFruitType = colProductTypeRange(Application.Match(currentProductNameRange.Value, colProductNameRange, 0))
End Function
```

I thought the more arguments I needed the slower it would be but it's actually quite the opposite. Now my function is way faster than the original Excel Formula. Thanks to all that helped, comment if my variable notation is wrong.

Comment: two comments: 1) it's generally best practice to include the final result in the original question, to help future seekers find the result. and 2) you're turning off Screen Update while the macro is running, right? I'm not sure if it's necessary in this code, but that's trick-zero for any fast-and-many calculations in VBA codes.

Answer (score 14):

I'm assuming that names have been changed to protect the innocent, but just in case they've not been...

#### These are terrible names. All of them.

- Function names should have verb-noun names and be `PascalCased`. So instead of `CUSTOMFUNCTION` should be `GetCustomMatch` (or *something* like that. I can't say because you've ommitted any actual names...)
- Parameters should be `camelCase` and tell me what *kind* of data
  should be passed in and **NEVER** should they be numbered the way
  this is. So, maybe this instead (again, I have to guess because I
  have no clue):

  ```
  Function GetCustomMatch(LookupRange As Range, lastYearsSalesRange as Range, iJustDontKnowWhatThisIsRange as Range) As String
  ```
- Don't use hungarian notation. Just... please don't. It should be
  **killed with fire and buried out back**.

  [image: kill it with fire]

#### Other Stuff

- Some of your "Values" are used in multiple places. Store them in a
  constant and use that constant anywhere they show up. (Of course,
  use meaningful names for them.)
- I have a feeling that `sTableMatchingFieldLookup` and `...Result` should be actual ranges instead of strings. String typing is bad. If you insist on keeping them as strings, store the values as constants.
- You should be able to pick up some performance by setting `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`. This [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16706186/3198973) has a pretty good example of what you're trying to do.

#### Things you did right

- You exit early if you've already found a match before performing the lookup rather than nesting `if` statements.

Comment: Hungarian notation doesn't even deserve a proper burial.

Comment: I'm sorry if this came off kind of harsh. We don't get many VBA questions, so I always get excited when I see one come through. It's just very difficult to give a proper review when all of the names have been basically obfuscated "to protect the innocent".

Comment: @ckuhn203 Thanks a lot for the help. My teacher taught us this way of naming variables, I never knew it was wrong. As I stated before, sorry about name changes, my company can be a little paranoid. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. It's ok to change names for the reason you did, but you should try to make them reasonable. It helps us help you. Your teacher taught you to use Hungarian notation either because *that's what he was taught* or because he came from a world of untyped (or perhaps weakly typed) languages. I highly recommend that you read [this article by Joel Spolsky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html). If you don't know of Joel, he's largely responsible for the creation of Excel & VBA (as we know it) and Stack Overflow.

Comment: The short story is that Hungarian notation isn't wrong. The way you (and most people) used it is.

Comment: Very interesting article. I tried the deactivation proposed in SO thread but it took longer than before (probably due to the thousand deactivation the function does). Also tried to wrap the deactivation in a sub but it took the same time as before.

Comment: ++, haha im loving this answer

Comment: @ckuhn203 I found the solution! I post it below.